# Hudson email ext plugin bug?

Tags: email, plugins, hudson, email-ext

I am getting an error using my email ext plugin from hudson. 
I am trying send an email to the following schema:

```
"< firstName >_< LastName >@< subgroup >.< companyName >.com
```

ex: John_Doe@stacks.stackoverflow.com

I cannot send emails to this address via the email extension plugin. 
The regular email generator works with this address schema.

I am wondering if the Address Checker module in the plugin is too strict about the address name.

Is there any workaround?

## I get the following spew from Hudson:

```
Jun 22, 2009 2:48:53 PM hudson.plugins.emailext.ExtendedEmailPublisher sendMail
WARNING: Could not send email.
javax.mail.internet.AddressException: Illegal address in string ``''
    at javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress.(InternetAddress.java:94)
    at hudson.plugins.emailext.ExtendedEmailPublisher.createMail(ExtendedEmailPublisher.java:287)
    at hudson.plugins.emailext.ExtendedEmailPublisher.sendMail(ExtendedEmailPublisher.java:249)
    at hudson.plugins.emailext.ExtendedEmailPublisher._perform(ExtendedEmailPublisher.java:241)
    at hudson.plugins.emailext.ExtendedEmailPublisher.perform(ExtendedEmailPublisher.java:199)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractRunner.performAllBuildStep(AbstractBuild.java:372)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractRunner.performAllBuildStep(AbstractBuild.java:360)
    at hudson.model.Build$RunnerImpl.cleanUp(Build.java:188)
    at hudson.model.Run.run(Run.java:962)
    at hudson.model.Build.run(Build.java:112)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:93)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:119)
```

Answer (score 1):

Is this really how you have it in Hudson?

```
"< firstName >_< LastName >@< subgroup >.< companyName >.com
```

(you have an open quote but no close quote)

If so, that may be your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Yup this is a bug ([HUDSON-7057](http://issues.hudson-ci.org/browse/HUDSON-7057)).

Based off of the latest code in the trunk:

this fails: " email1@server.com email2@server.com"
works as expected: "email1@gmail.com email2@gmail.com "
works as expected: "email1@gmail.com email2@gmail.com"

Scrutinize what you put in the recipient list for random whitespace.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using that plugin too and I haven't had any such problems.

The warning appears to be complaining about your configuration. Maybe you'd want to double-check the email address that you typed? Whitespace as separator char for multiple emails? Also, double-check your sytem configuration and make sure you've configured your SMTP server or the default suffix correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You can browse the [code](http://fisheye4.atlassian.com/browse/hudson/trunk/hudson/plugins/email-ext/src/main/java/hudson/plugins/emailext/ExtendedEmailPublisher.java?r=19390) but I would guess that the javax mail validator is not too strict - it's built in to java.    In the latest code, I don't see the InternetAddress(String) constructor on line 287, so I wonder what version of the plugin you are currently using.

Also, what options do you have selected for email?  Send to culprits?